# Is this kind of addition of ordinals incremental?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I just want to ask about if in ZFC the following form of sum operation on ordinals fulfills the below mentioned properties.

Define: $\alpha +^+ \beta = max (\alpha + \beta, \beta + \alpha)$

where: $max(\alpha,\beta)=\gamma \equiv_{df} \\(\alpha > \beta \land \gamma=\alpha) \lor (\beta > \alpha \land \gamma=\beta) \lor (\alpha = \beta \land \gamma = \alpha)$

, and $``+"$ is the usual ordinal adddition.

> Does it follow that:
>
> $\gamma > \delta \to \gamma +^+ \alpha > \delta+^+\alpha$
>
> $\gamma \neq \delta \to \gamma +^+ \alpha \neq  \delta +^+ \alpha$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not get strict inequalities: Consider $\gamma:=\omega^2+1>\delta=\omega^2$ and $\alpha=\omega$. We have $$\gamma+\alpha=\delta+\alpha>\alpha+\gamma>\alpha+\delta.$$

Comment: An incremental (and commutative!) alternative is obtained by considering instead the Hessenberg or natural sum, where you write ordinals in Cantor normal sum and then add them "coordinatewise".

Comment: what I wanted to do is to make $\gamma +^+ \alpha = \omega^2 + \omega + 1$, while $\delta +^+ \alpha = \omega^2 + \omega$, in other words for any ordinal $\beta$ the ordinal  $\beta +^+ \alpha$ would move $\beta$ forwards by $\alpha$ length.

Comment: The Hessenberg sum should work for you, then. It is usually denoted as $\alpha\#\beta$.